# What is the best way to cache the last overlay object in IOS SWIFT.

Tags: ios, swift, caching, overlay

My idea is to store the last overlay object to userDefaults or a file and retrieve it when the mapview loads in offline . I have tried with route-me and osmSharp but I am looking for a more simpler solution which would not require an external lib. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Nguyen, you'll likely want to use Core Data as it provides you with a way to store things locally. NSUserDefaults isn't really the best place to save this type of stuff as NSUserDefaults is more for things like settings.

A great starting point for learning more about Core Data can be to look at Big Nerd Ranch's open source project: https://github.com/bignerdranch/CoreDataStack

Answer (score 2):

Use CoreData, convert your object to nsdata and save it